# How can I access to min and max value of x and y axis in pfgplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to access to `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` values of an axis in `pgfplots`. If these values are explicitly defined by user I know that I can use the `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` command. But what if they are automatically chosen without user specification?

I try also with `\pgfplots@xmin` but I think it is a constant and not what I want..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` et al. for axis even without specifying min and max manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false]
        \addplot[domain=0:5] {x^2} node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false]
        \addplot[domain=0:10] {x^2} node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It did not work for me because I used it in the wrong way.. What if I want to use this value as a number? For example if I add `\addplot {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}};` to your example I get an error..

Comment: @Red That's actually the same as `\addplot {5};` which shouldn't work either.

Comment: @percusse `\addplot {5};` works, it plots a constant line at value y=5

Comment: @Red Sorry my mistake, what I mean is that the min max values are computed after the plots are collected, since it needs to find a range to limit the plot. You are trying to get it before the values are set.