# How can I draw 25 horizontal lines instead of these 25 marked samples?

Tags: pgfplots

Instead of the samples which were marked via `mark=-`, I would like to have horizontal lines that fill the entire `axis` from left to right. Had the idea to tune the dashes via `mark size=6cm` but I did not find out how to clip them at the plot's borders.

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp,
siunitx
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
height=5cm,
width=6cm,
scale only axis=true,
%
xlabel={\(\alpha\) in \si{\degree}},
ylabel={\(\sin{(\alpha)}\)},
%
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,}, xmajorgrids={false}, ymajorgrids={false}
]
\addplot+[domain=0:360, samples=25, only marks, mark=-] {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean `xcomb`?

Comment: I think it might work, but how would I get them to the right edge?

Comment: You could abuse grid lines: use `ytick=data` and activate grid lines for y. Would that be acceptable or do you ever need y tick labels?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Yes, I do. It's just one of four pictures in a group plot for a little showcase of  [quantization](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&q=quantization).

Comment: @percusse I think it might work, but how would I get them to the right edge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp,
siunitx
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
height=5cm,
width=6cm,
scale only axis=true,
%
xlabel={\(\alpha\) in \si{\degree}},
ylabel={\(\sin{(\alpha)}\)},
%
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,}, xmajorgrids={false}, ymajorgrids={false},
after end axis/.code={
\foreach \i in {90,105,...,270} {% to avoid duplicated lines
\pgfmathparse{sin(\i)} ;
\draw(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfmathresult)--(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfmathresult) ;} ;
}
}
]
\addplot+[domain=0:360, samples=25, only marks, mark=-] {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To avoid that 4pt offset, you can use `\draw(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfmathresult)--(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfmathresult) ;`

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip I didn't knew.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, I got it from this site myself. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124199/